# Python Flask API returns empty response for time consuming computation

Tags: python, flask, web-development-server

I built A python Flask API (uses Swagger). This API calls an internal function that is a bit time-consuming for some large (CSV) files. Now, when I run this API on Postman or even when  I call this API from the Client side on the web, it gives an "empty response" or "Error: socket hang up". However, the process keeps running at the back and after some time generates slack alerts (that is a part of the function). The issue is I have to ensure that this API Returns the result to postman or to UI, for that matter, because based on my response (bool), the UI shows something to the end user. Here is my swagger API config (not showing the import statements, assume libraries are correctly imported)

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
api = Api(app, version='1.0', title='CATALOG-OPS-TECHNOLOGY', description='All catalog processing and images\' download / upload are handled by these APIs')
validate_scraped_file_ns = api.namespace('Validate-Scraped-File', description='Validate the raw scraped file')
validate_scraped_file_request_model = api.model('validateScrapedFileRequest', {
    'index': fields.String(required=True),
    'date_sc': fields.String(required=True),
})
validate_scraped_file_response_model = api.model('validateScrapedFileResponse', {
    'result': fields.Boolean(required=True),
    'validation_url': fields.String(required=False),
    'variation_url': fields.String(required=False),
})
@validate_scraped_file_ns.route('/validate_scraped_file')
class ValidationVariationResource(Resource):
    try:
        @validate_scraped_file_ns.expect(validate_scraped_file_request_model)
        @validate_scraped_file_ns.marshal_with(validate_scraped_file_response_model)
        def post(self):

            request_data = api.payload
            index = request_data['index']
            date_sc = request_data['date_sc']

            response = validate_scraped_file(index, date_sc)

            result = response['response']
            validation_url = response['validation_url']
            variation_url = response['variation_url']

            return {
                'result': result,
                'validation_url': validation_url,
                'variation_url': variation_url
            }
    except Exception as e:
        post_slack_message(e)
```

I have tried adding a timeout in the app like...

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['TIMEOUT'] = 900
CORS(app)
```

...but this hasn't helped. Some Files are done in a min while some take up to 10-12 mins! It is the `validate_scraped_file` function that takes a bit of time to return the response thereby causing this failure! I want to ensure that we always get a response from this API, even if we need to wait, be it requested from Postman or Client App! Help me fix this, please?

Comment: some web servers may kill request when it works longer that 30seconds - at least web server Apache with PHP had this restriction. All for security and [Denial-of-service attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack). There is popular method to run separated process in background or use external programs like `Celery` and send `unique number` to user/browser - and `JavaScript` can periodically sends request with this `unique number` to ask if task is completed. If task is not completed then it can display progress bar.

Comment: [Background Tasks with Celery — Flask Documentation (2.3.x)](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/patterns/celery/)

Comment: Thank you so much, let me check the documentation.

Comment: @furas Just confirming, the documentation says this:

"...If your application has a long running task, such as processing some uploaded data or sending email, you don’t want to wait for it to finish during a request. Instead, use a task queue to send the necessary data to another process that will run the task in the background while the request returns immediately."

Well, what I show on the UI, depends on the response (bool) so my response and the subsequent steps are indeed dependent on the result of the computation. Will it still be possible?

Comment: so your UI may need `JavaScript` to check periodically if there is result on Celery - and meanwhile it may display `progress bar`

Comment: Ok. Will deep dive, thanks a lot

Comment: I think I saw example in some question on Stackoverflow but I can't find it.

Comment: So I went through the documentation and this will need a lot of infra-level changes. Is it by any chance, possible via some other simpler approach? @furas

Comment: accidentally I found question which use Celery: [python - Celery with dask not woeking - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77637778/celery-with-dask-not-woeking?noredirect=1#comment136874076_77637778)